# Insomnia/postman returning id: null when sending a post request

Tags: python, docker, sqlite

Im sending a post request for creating a room that adds the room, its temp and the date of reading, when sending to postman/insomnia it returns a id: null response. Also when sending get method for getting temp and deleting a room, im getting MultipleObjectsFoundError
pony.orm.core.MultipleObjectsFoundError: Multiple objects were found. Use Room.select(...) to retrieve them. Im using SQlite and docker, no frontend

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pony import orm
from pony.orm import *
from datetime import datetime
from pony.converting import str2datetime
DB = orm.Database()

app = Flask(__name__)


class Room(DB.Entity):
    room_name = orm.Required(str)
    temperature = orm.Required(float)
    date = orm.Required(datetime)


DB.bind(provider="sqlite",
    filename="database.sqlite", create_db=True)

DB.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)


@app.route('/room', methods=['POST'])
@db_session
def add_room():
    room = Room(
        room_name=request.json['room_name'],
        temperature=float(request.json['temperature']),
        date=datetime.strptime(request.json['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')
    )
    return {"id": room.id}, 201


@app.route('/room/<name>/<date>', methods=['GET'])
@db_session
def get_temperature(name, date):
    room = Room.get(room_name=name, date=datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    if room is None:
        return {'error': 'Room not found'}, 404
    return {'temperature': room.temperature}


@app.route('/room/<name>/average', methods=['GET'])
@db_session
def get_average_temperature(name):
    avg_temperature = avg(room.temperature for room in select(
        room for room in Room if room.room_name == name))
    if avg_temperature is None:
        return {'error': 'Room not found'}, 404
    return {'average_temperature': avg_temperature}



@app.route('/room/<name>/<date>', methods=['DELETE'])
@db_session
def delete_temperature(name, date):
    room = Room.get(room_name=name, date=datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    if room is None:
        return {'error': 'Room not found'}, 404
    room.delete()
    return {}, 204


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='8080', host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.10.7
WORKDIR /main
ADD . /main
COPY requirements.txt req.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r req.txt
EXPOSE 5001
CMD ["python", "main.py"]

All this is running in virtual env named "flask"

I tried chatGPT but nothing. I tried changing the return id: room.id but it still return the id: null, idk what to do anymore, the project is 99% finished